# Symfony2 assetic (with twig) sass (scss filter) imports and watch

Tags: symfony, twig, sass, watch, assetic

I am trying to use one main file where I just use include sass syntax to include other scss files in order I want, it works fine but only problem assetic seems won't follow the watch of files which are includes and I had to do manually dump, either do some modifications into the main file I use for includes.
I do not expect such troubles when use pure sass watch.

Probably anyone could suggest workaround over this issue?